# show custom post types for a month

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type called "cpt_docs":
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

```
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'cpt_docs',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Docs' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Doc' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

I have tabs with months and i want to show the "docs" for that month.
I need to show the custom post types in the home page, bu i dont how can i do that.

Should i use a hard coded sql query or there is another way?

thk all.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_get_archives

Comment: but this shows ALL the posts by date.I need to show dates only for my custom post type.

Comment: remember its not in a template file, its on the homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it works if i use a filter like this:

```
add_filter('getarchives_where','docs_filter');

function docs_filter($where_clause) {
  return "WHERE post_type = 'cpt_docs' AND post_status = 'publish'";
}
```

Thk all.